# Correctly selecting a web element through xpath with Python and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping, siblings

I am triying to do scraping in a web with this structure.

```
<div>
    <div class = “class1” >
    <div class = “class2” >
    <div class = “class3” >
    <div style = “clear: both; ” >
</div>
<div>
    <div class = “class1” >
    <div class = “class2” >
    <div class = “class3” >
    <div style = “clear: both; ” >
</div>    
<div>
    <div class = “class1” >
    <div class = “class2” >
    <div class = “class3” >
    <div style = “clear: both; ” >
</div>
```

in each section there is diferent information. I want to search a specific word in the class1´s and if this word exist there then I print the information. After of this I have problems. After I want to get the information in class 3 of this section. For example, if my class1 in the first section has "this word" then I Want to get the class3 information in this section.

My code is this:

```
cs1 = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("class1")
for i in cs1:
    information = i.text
    if "this word" in information:
        print(information)
        infclass3 = i.find_element_by_xpath('//following-sibling::div[@class = "class3"]')
        print(infclass3.text)
```

The problem is this: I get the class1 information with "this word", but the information about the class3 in this section I dont. Always it print the class3 in the first section, every time. for example if "this word" is in the second and third section I get something like this:

```
information of class1 - Section 2
information of class3 - Section 1
information of class1 - Section 3
information of class3 - Section 1
```

then the information in the line 1 and 3 is right. But in the line 2 and 4 is not, 1. Because is repeat 2. Because in the section 1 is not "this word"

Thanks for the help.

I Hope you have a nice day :)

Comment: Why loop and not get element(s) you need directly: `driver.find_element(s)_by_xpath('//div[@class="class1" and contains(text(),"this word")]/../div[@class="class3"]')`

Comment: I dont know what I am doing wrong but when I run your code
I dont get nothing

Comment: maybe then you need post more of your HTML (at least how the section with "this word" looks like)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for the help

Finally I got it in this way:

```
infclass3 = i.find_element_by_xpath('following-sibling::*[2]')
```

I get the class1 element and later with `'following-sibling::*[2]'` I find the siblings and select the one  located in the position 2 that corresponding to class3 .

Thanks for the attention

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you are trying to get the `class3` element from the context of a `class1` element, this means that it will only look for children of the `class1` element currently assigned to `i`... with this in mind the selector for the `class3` element that you want is:

```
infclass3 = i.find_element_by_xpath('../div[@class="class3"]')
```

Comment: thank you. You are right with your observation, but I tried with your solution and  it didn´t work.  I got it with 'following-sibling::*[2]'